# Include namespace in Rails 3.1 namespaced application's HAML views

Tags: namespaces, ruby-on-rails-3.1, haml

My Rails 3.1 application is completely implemented inside a namespace. When I call views, this namespace is not included, so that I have to type the full qualified name of each class each time. I guess this is a bug or at least a missing feature. How can I include my namespace Aef::Newman automatically in each view context, so that I don't have to type the full qualified name each time?

Notice that the following statement inside the HAML view template fails because the method include can not be found:

```
- include Aef::Newman
```

Both components of this namespace are of type Module. For example, my controllers are located in app/controllers/aef/newman and the application controller looks like this:

```
module Aef
  module Newman
    class ApplicationController < ActionController::Base

      protect_from_forgery

    end
  end
end
```

There is a controller named HandledAddressesController which looks like this:

```
module Aef
  module Newman
    class HandledAddressesController < ApplicationController

      def index
        @handled_addresses = HandledAddress.all
      end

    end
  end  
end
```

Notice, that even the HandledAddress model is actually named Aef::Newman::HandledAddress and is located in app/models/aef/newman/handled_address.rb .

My routes.rb looks like this:

```
resources :handled_addresses, controller: 'aef/newman/handled_addresses, only: :index
```

The view template path is app/views/aef/newman/handled_addresses/index.haml.haml

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Firstly, you shouldn't really be using constants inside a template. Set some instance variables or make some helpers to do it.

But, if you really want access to your namespaced constants (classes, modules, etc) then in an initializer you could:

```
ActionView::CompiledTemplates.send :include, Aef::Newman
```

ActionView compiles all templates into this module.

Comment: Could you further explain why you consider it a bad idea to use constants inside the view templates?